# Can't make IAP work in sandbox (SWIFT) in simulator

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, xcode6

transactionState is always returning .Failed
any ideas? why this is happening
i have added new sandbox user in itunes connect and using its credentials in simulator to make the purchase in sandbox mode and it wont work.
it work on my physical iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-app purchase does not work in the simulator. It only works on an actual device.  I'll try to find the documentation that states this.

### EDIT

The closest thing I could find is under the Xcode 5 release notes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc5_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH2-SW302

- StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Although this is for Xcode 5, I believe it's safe to assume the same holds true for Xcode 6.